# Fast loading of PNG image into an array in java

Tags: java, performance, png, javax.imageio

I want to load (and decode) PNG images and convert them into a one-dimensional array in Java. I can obviously do this with ImageIO.read() and then copy the pixels into the array, but that consumes twice the memory (the raster + the final array) and it involves more processing time than I would like.

How should I go about this? Worst-case I can implement the PNG spec myself, but that seems like a rather involved task. Ideally I'd like a PNG implementation that I can "plug" into. Less ideal but still fine would be an easy to understand (unlike the com.sun code) PNG reader that I can (and would be allowed to) modify.

Comment: what type should the array have? byte[]? In that case I can't see how you should "copy the pixels" into the array. If it's a byte-array, why don't you load the PNG file content into an array?

Comment: @aioobe: Presumably he wants to have the *decoded* image data in an array, not the actual bytes in the PNG file.

Comment: Yes, I want the decoded image data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If what you're trying to do is get the pixel data as an array, then you can use `ImageIO.read()` to get a `BufferedImage` and then use `BufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()` to get the `DataBuffer`. From there, you need to check what type of `BufferedImage` you have in order to determine how to cast the `DataBuffer`. E.g. if you have a `TYPE_INT_RGB` image, then you should cast to a `DataBufferInt` and then you can call `DataBufferInt.getData()` to retrieve the `int[]` which contains the data. What you get this way is not a copy---it's the actual array backing the `BufferedImage`.

**However**, there is a big caveat to all of this: `ImageIO.read()` will often NOT give you the type of image you want. E.g., you'll frequently get TYPE_CUSTOM, which you can't do anything useful with except copy to the image type you actually want.

**So**, you'll only be able to get your image data via `ImageIO.read()` without making a second copy if you're fortunate enough that `ImageIO.read()` gives you the image in the format you want. If you want to check what types are available from `ImageIO`, you can call `ImageIO.getImageReaders()` to get an `Iterator` over all of the readers which claim to be able to read your stream, and then you can use `ImageReader.getImageTypes(0)` to get an `Iterator` over image types which the reader can read. You *might* find a reader which will give you the image type you want this way, but don't hold your breath.

Unless your images are huge, copying them is actually pretty fast. If your images *are* huge, though, you might have to resort to using `BufferedImage.getRGB()` to write the raw image data out to disk one row at a time (but do it compressed, use a `GZIPOutputStream`), let the original image be garbage collected, create a new `BufferedImage` of the desired type, and finally read the rows back from disk, writing them to the new image using `BufferedImage.setRGB()`. (I wrote something to do this just a few days ago, hence the details are rather fresh in my mind. The LGPL'd source for it is [here](http://vassalengine.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vassalengine/VASSAL-src/branches/uckelman-working/src/VASSAL/tools/image/FileImageTypeConverter.java?revision=7344&view=markup).)

Comment: I actually tried this, and it worked fine..  I thought. The bytes in my image are all -1... not exactly a valid value for an image.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want a 1D array?  What is the bigger purpose?

On that hinges any recommendations.

You can usually decode a PNG to a memory-accessible bitmap, (`ImageIO.read()` returns a `BufferedImage`, which is precisely that) and just access its pixels directly ... as a 1D array (using `BufferedImage.getRaster().getDataBuffer()`).

Answer (score 0):

use [Java readfully()](http://www.java-examples.com/read-byte-array-file-using-datainputstream)

Comment: This makes sense only if he wants the raw bytes from the PNG file, instead of the *decoded* image data.

Comment: Which *is* what I want (I amended the question).